# Any way to prevent that last char of a string from replacing in java

Tags: java, string

Let's say that want to add `?` after each letter in a string.

```
String letters = "A@B@C@D"; //Split by @
String splitLetters[]=letters.split("@");

for(String ltr: splitLetters)
    System.out.println(ltr+"?");
```

the output will be like:
`A? B? C? D?`

What I want is to prevent that last char from getting the change.
I want only the first letters to be changed.

**Note:**

replacing `@` with `?` in a direct way like (`...replace("@","?")`) won't work. **The code above is only an example.**

Comment: Also *"replacing `@` with `?` in a direct way like (`...replace("@","?")`) won't work"* why? I'd say it's pretty important information to add to your question.

Comment: Agreed - it seems that if we know what the criteria actually are, then we ought to be able to devise a regexp for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost thre! Just use `for...loop` and check if current letter last or not.

```
String letters = "A@B@C@D"; //Split by @
String splitLetters[] = letters.split("@");

for (int i = 0; i < splitLetters.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(splitLetters[i]);

    if (i + 1 < splitLetters.length)
        System.out.println('?');
}
```

Comment: No need for the `if` - the exceptional case can be moved outside the loop.  See my prior answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is actually getting changed in your example, so it's difficult to figure out what you want to do.

If it's just that you don't want to print out the question mark after the last substring, then:

```
int k;
for (k=0; k<splitLetters.length-1; k++)
    System.out.println(splitLetters[k] + "?");
System.out.println(splitLetters[k]);
```

You can apply similar reasoning to your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do it (as already described in the existing answers). The following solution is based on your own solution with the required change:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String letters = "A@B@C@D"; // Split by @
        String splitLetters[] = letters.split("@");
        boolean firstStrPrinted = false;
        for (String ltr : splitLetters) {
            if (firstStrPrinted) {
                System.out.print("?" + ltr);
            } else {
                System.out.print(ltr);
                firstStrPrinted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A?B?C?D
```

Here, a `boolean firstStrPrinted` has been used to track if the first string has been printed. If not, do not print the `?` and update it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> let's say that want to add ? after each letter in a string.
> How about this?

This works by replacing the @ sign followed by a character or end of string with the same character followed by the letter and the ? mark.  It uses a back reference to capture the character.

```
String[] strs = { "A@B@C@D", "ABC@BBB@CCC@DDDD" };
for (String text : strs) {
    String rep = text.replaceAll("(\\w)@|$", "$1? ");
    System.out.println(text + " ->  " + rep);
}
```

Prints

```
A@B@C@D ->  A? B? C? D? 
ABC@BBB@CCC@DDDD ->  ABC? BBB? CCC? DDDD?
```

If this does not meet your requirements, please provide more specific guidelines.

Comment: Note.  I put spaces after the ? because that is what you showed.